# Imported node module that exports firebaseui causes jest tests to fail with " ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have a NPM package which I've written myself and exports, among other things, certain React components that import `firebaseui`. Note that `firebaseui` requires the DOM to exist in order to run. This is how I'm exporting them from the package in `index.ts`

```
export * from './login/login_view'
export * from './login/login_widget'
export * from './firebaseAuth'
```

I have React project that has tests which import certain things from this package. However, it **does not** import anything that uses `firebaseui`, aka nothing from the above files. It also doesn't import anything that relies on anything from those files.

When I run tests, I get `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. When I remove the above exports from the NPM package, the error disappears.

Is there something wrong with how I'm exporting things from my package?

When I run the tests with `yarn test --env=jsdom`, they still fail.

Answer (score 0):

yow broh!! at yow `tsconfig.json` add a "dom" item

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
...
     "lib": [
        "DOM",
        "ES2020",
        "ES2019"
     ]
...
   }
}
```